# Matlab will not plot my function for some reason

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I got an assignment in class and was able to do a majority of it but it is giving me some trouble. If I manually copy and paste my code into the command window then I can get everything to run and plot but if just call on the function it will give me outputs but will not plot for some reason. any ideas?

I also tried my friends code which in my eyes is almost identical except, for some reason his allows him to call on it and it will plot. I've already been working on just this small amount for 6 hours today and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
function [totalheat1,totalheat2] = dheat(Tday,Tnight)


foot=10*sum('Todd');
height=9; %ft
Ctm=0.35; %BTU/lb degF 
mt= 20000; %lbs
A= foot + 4*((sqrt(foot)*height)); %surface area of house (ft^2)
R=25; %degF*ft^2*hour/BTU
To=30; %degF

dt=0.1;
t=dt:dt:24;
n=24/dt;
Td=Tday;
Tn=Tnight;

%regime 1
for i=1:n
  Q1(i)=dt*((A*(Td-To))/(R));  
end

%regime 2

therm=[1:240];
therm(1:70)=Tn;
therm(71:100)=Td;
therm(101:160)=Tn;
therm(161:230)=Td;
therm(231:240)=Tn;

Td=therm(1);

for i=1:n
   Q=dt*((A*(Td-To))/(R));
   chgT=(Q)/(Ctm*mt);
   Ti=Td-chgT;
   if Ti< therm(i)
       Q=(therm(i)-Ti)*(Ctm*mt);
       if Q<3000
           F(i)=Q;
           temp(i)=Td;
       else
          F(i)=3000;
          temp(i)=Ti+((3000)/(Ctm*mt));

       end
   else
       F(i)=0;
       temp(i)=Ti;
   end
   Td=temp(i);
end


totalheat1=sum(Q1);
totalheat2=sum(F);

figure(1)
plot(t,temp)

figure(2)
plot(t,Q1,t,F)

end
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Did you try to add `t`, `temp`,`Q1` and `F` to function output and plot it outside? Did you try debugging it?

Comment: This is the first coding class I've ever taken and I'm not really sure what else I can do with the code. I've looked over the code for about 7 hours now and I can't see why it's not working. I've even compared it to my friend's code which does work but mine does not. I'm completely lost!

Comment: In the MATLAB editor, click on the left margin at the first line of your function, you should see a red dot appear. This is a break point. Now when you run your function, execution will stop at the break point. In the editor you will now be able to click "Step", and MATLAB will execute the line of code and move to the next. Repeatedly press this button, and observe what your code does. You can also place the cursor on the line after the loop and click "Run to cursor", so you don't need to sit and watch every iteration of the loop being executed.

Answer (score 1):

First, Make sure you hit `close all force` before calling your function.
This will close all open (but maybe not visible) figures.

Next, this snippet explicitly tells which figure and axes to use:

```
f1 = figure();
ax1 = axes(f1);
p1 = plot(ax1, t,temp);

f2 = figure();
ax2 = axes(f2);
p2 = plot(ax2, t, Q1, t, F);
```

If it still does not work:
try passing a `struct` containing `handles` to those figures/axes as a third parameter of your function. in a  script:

```
s = struct();
s.f1 = figure();
s.ax1 = axes(f1);

s.f2 = figure();
s.ax2 = axes(f2);

dheat(Tday,Tnight,s)
```

and the function:

```
function [s,totalheat1,totalheat2] = dheat(Tday,Tnight,s)
```

and the plotting part would then look like:

```
p1 = plot(s.ax1, t,temp);
p2 = plot(s.ax2, t, Q1, t, F);
```

Personally, I would prefer returning the calculated values and calling plot specific things from a script. `p1` and `p2` could be omitted.